# Is 'the DAO' dissolved?

Tags: the-dao

Given Buterins statement of a hard fork to return all the money after theDAO hack, does this mean that the DAO is unofficially dissolved? Officially when the hard fork has happened.

Comment: An interesting question is how will the token holders who paid > 1 ETH  = 100 DAO tokens be tracked down if they are to be compensated for the excess over 1 ETH=100 DAO. Some tokens have been transferred to exchanges and other transferred. The excess ethers for the holders that paid > 1 ETH  = 100 DAO are in the extraBalances account. While the original addresses can be determined from The DAO event log, some tokens have moved addresses.

Comment: According to [Thoughts on The DAO Hack](http://hackingdistributed.com/2016/06/17/thoughts-on-the-dao-hack/), funds in the extraBalances account will not be accessible if the ETH in The DAO are returned to The DAO token holders.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/17/critical-update-re-dao-vulnerability/

I think the answer to your question is YES, CONDITIONAL on support from miners as described below:

> Miners and mining pools should resume allowing transactions as normal, wait for the soft fork code and stand ready to download and run it **if they agree with this path forward for the Ethereum ecosystem**. DAO token holders and ethereum users should sit tight and remain calm. Exchanges should feel safe in resuming trading ETH.

If the miners to not agree with the proposed solution (starting with the softfork described above) then the following sentence (describing the later hardfork) cannot occur in the manner Vitalik currently describes:

> This will later be followed up by a hard fork which will give token holders the ability to recover their ether.

Mr. Vbuterin has confirmed that the miners are free to make their own choice in the matter:

> **I personally believe that the soft fork that has been proposed to lock up the ether inside the DAO to block the attack is, on balance, a good idea**, and I personally, on balance, support it, and I support the fork being developed and encourage miners to upgrade to a client version that supports the fork. That said, I recognize that there are very heavy arguments on both sides, and that either direction would have seen very heavy opposition...
>
> ... **I will not attempt to prevent or discourage them from speaking their minds including in public forums, or even from lobbying miners to resist the soft fork. I steadfastly refuse to villify anyone who is taking the opposite side from me on this particular issue.**"

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4oj7ql/personal_statement_regarding_the_fork/